# Question about GCC8's stack-clash-protection clashing with stack-check

Tags: gcc, gcc8

I have some code running well under GCC7. It enables fstack-check flag. Now when I switch to GCC8 without code change, I encounter the following error:

```
c1plus: error: ‘-fstack-check=’ and ‘-fstack-clash_protection’ are mutually exclusive.  Disabling ‘-fstack-check=’ [-Werror]
```

Clearly it wants me to remove the stack-check. However I did not enable the "stack-clash-protection" flag, why would It come into play? Is this flag enabled by default in GCC8?

Comment: GCC can be configured with some default options.  Apparently your distro configured `-fstack-clash_protection` to be on by default.